# maven don't read suite.xml file

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, testng

I have suite.xml file where I have mentioned which of my test cases that should run. In pom.xml I set the path of the file. When I do maven test from eclipse it runs all my test cases. It seems that maven don't read my suite.xml file because I try to run it with wrong suite.xml structure and there was no errors.

Here is part of my pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <suite>suite.xml</suite>
    </properties>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXMLFiles>
                        <suiteXMLFile>src/test/java/com/epam/suites/${suite}</suiteXMLFile>
                    </suiteXMLFiles> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and suite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SuiteName">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node should be `suiteXmlFiles`/`suiteXmlFile` and not `suiteXMLFiles`/`suiteXMLFile`: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/com/epam/suites/${suite}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```